# How to upload an .sb2 file to the Scratch website?

Tags: mit-scratch

If I have a Scratch .sb2 file on my computer and also have an account on [scratch.mit.edu](https://scratch.mit.edu) how can I upload that project file to the website so it can be accessed there?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Scratch wiki](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/How_to_Save_a_Project#Uploading_a_Project):

> To upload a previously downloaded project, navigate to the project whose contents are to be replaced. (If the file was created offline, create a blank project for the file to replace.) Click 'File', then from the dropdown menu, click 'load from Your Computer'. Select the correct file, then click 'Open'. The project will then load onto the Scratch Editor.

This works for both SB3 and the old SB2 format. From the [Scratch wiki](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Porting_Scratch_Projects):

> To convert SB or SB2 to SB3, open the file in Scratch 3 and save it.

This was confirmed in 2019 by [this forum thread](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/352061/).